# Receiving text with C# SDK

Tags: sms, ringcentral

While exploring RingCentral C# SDK, we have a requirement of receiving SMS.

I know how to use C# SDK for sending SDK, but wanted to get an idea of receiving it.

I am not sure any plugin I need to fit here.

I haven't got proper answer even searching the Internet.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive inbound SMS by subscribing to event notifications for new SMS or by polling the message store API.

## Subscribing for Event Notifications

There are to ways to subscribe, using PubNub and using Webhooks.

Using `PubNub`, you can receive SMS. Check it out here:

https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-csharp-client/blob/master/RingCentral.Test/SubscripotionTest.cs#L31

If you want `WebHook`, check the reference:

https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-csharp-client/blob/master/RingCentral.Test/WebHookTest.cs

## Polling

The direct API of RingCentral APIs to receive SMS content is:

```
/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/message-store/<message id>/content/<attachment id>
```

Here you need to put the `message id` and the `attachment id` which you can use in your C#.